# How to check productions logs after deployment in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

I deployed my app using capistrano and passenger (+ apache). Now when i go to the link it tells me

```
"We're sorry, but something went wrong."
```

Where can i find the logs to investigate more on the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does this error occur when you call your Rails app? Have you looked at the Rails `log/production.log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this path :

> /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: i am using centos. so any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can login/ssh into the server and check them in logs/production.log

Comment: yes but it only shows the logs from the capistrano deploy. look here - http://pastebin.com/zNbvsGNK